# Get Lines between pattern 1 and pattern2 which may accure multiple times

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I try to print out the lines between two different patterns(including the patterns) which may accure multiple times in a file. The second pattern may accure besides the startpattern-endpattern-rhytm.

Example:

-File:

```
XYZ
XYY
BBB
XYX
AAA
AAB
BBB
XYW
AAA
AAC
AAD
BBB
```

-Output should be like:

```
AAA
AAB
BBB
AAA
AAC
AAD
BBB
```

I've already tried things like `awk '/AAA/{a=1}/BBB/{print;a=0}a'`.

Thank you.

Comment: The only issue I can see is that you are printing lines that match `/BBB/` regardless of the value of `a`: try changing to `awk '/AAA/{a=1} /BBB/ && a {print;a=0} a'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has to be `awk` just do:

```
awk -- '/AAA/,/BBB/{print}'
```

But it seems `sed` would also be perfectly suited for your case. So, analogously just do:

```
sed -ne '/AAA/,/BBB/p'
```

In both commands, use a comma to indicate that you want to consider all the lines starting from (and including) the one matching the first pattern, up to (and including) the line matching the second pattern.